# Listen for console.logs in WebView from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a web page that I don't control that logs things to the console, running inside a `WebView`. I want to catch these logs and maintain a list of them in the guest (my React Native app).

I don't have control over the code so just using `postMessage` instead of `console.log` isn't an option. One of my thoughts was to use a `Proxy`, like so:

```
window.console = new Proxy(window.console, {
  get: (object, key) => {
    alert(`console.${key} called`)
    return object[key]
  }
})
```

... and inject the code into the `WebView` (I could eventually change `alert` to `postMessage`. This didn't do anything and no alerts were displayed. If I just stick `alert(1)` in the injected code it shows up so everything is fine with the code injection. I also tried surrounding it with a try/catch block  and no errors were displayed either.

Here's my `WebView`, it looks pretty normal to me:

```
<WebView
  useWebKit={true}
  originWhitelist={[ '*' ]}
  source={{ uri: this.state.url }}
/>
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say much without seeing the code of the underlying object, but it's possible it's saving a reference to the `console.log` function before your code runs.  e.g. `class Foo { Foo() { this.logger = console.log; } fooLog(logMsg) { this.logger(logMsg); } }` In which case you'd have to make sure to replace `console.log` before the code that you don't control loads.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler the thing is, the parent class is running in a completely different space from the code in the webview afaik. The only method of communication I have is the `postMessage` api.